# Zoo Visitor Forgot password form not working

Tags: zoo-visitor, forgot-password

I'm using EE 2.8.1 and Visitor 1.3.32.

I have the following form on a /forgot-password template:

```
{exp:zoo_visitor:forgot_password error_handling="inline" reset_url="forgot-password" parse="inward"}
    {if password_sent}
            <h3>A password reset mail has been sent to the provided email.</h3>
    {if:else}
            <fieldset>
                    <p>
                            <label for="email" class="form-label">Your email:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-text" value="" />
                    </p>
                    {error:email}
            </fieldset>
            <p>
                            <input type="submit" value="Retrieve password" class="button" />
            </p>
    {/if}
{/exp:zoo_visitor:forgot_password}
```

When I submit the form, it returns to my home page and does not send an email. I have a sneaking suspicion that it has something to do with my htaccess file. However, I'm not adding any slashes, rather, removing them, etc:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Force non www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#remove trailing slash from URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$  /$1 [R=301,L] 

# Removes index.php from URLs
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Any thoughts here?

Answer (score 0):

I cleared my cache and this worked fine.